# Changing a custom animation in a Game Loop

Tags: android

I have in mind 3 or more ways to achieve what I want, so I want to know the best way to do it

I have a custom Game loop and I want to have multiple "animations" (where updating the game physics and rendering to the canvas on the SurfaceView differ from one GameState to another)

So I can just enhance my game loop a little and make it go through multiple while loops based on an object's variable gameState, or a switch in the inside
(in this case I will have the same Activity and SurfaceView the whole time)

OR I can switch between game states with removing the whole SurfaceView (let's say from a parent FrameLayout) and make a new one each time,
(this way I would have the same Activity, that changes view each time you lose the game for example)

OR I can change the whole Activity for each GameState,,,,

(There are some obvious differences like transitions between Activities and custom transitions in the first way to do it)

Could you please give me some thoughts and which way is the best ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're going to see at least a stutter if you try to restructure the app UI by removing and creating a new SurfaceView. Switching between Activities is going to cost you any control you would want over that transition and make it impossible to port your game to any other platform. I'd say the best way to go about it it would be to have a switch in your onDraw that changes based on game state.

Comment: This is the right idea. The whole point of a game loop is to refresh the UI as quickly and smoothly as possible. So you shouldn't do anything to break that premise.